# Does partitioning iTunes and iPhoto libraries make my Mac faster?

Tags: macos, mac, partitioning, itunes, iphoto

I have a

```
iMac (early 2009)
```

with

```
2,66 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo  
4 GB 1067 MHz DDR3  
640GB 7200-rpm Serial ATA hard drive
```

If I create a partition for the iTunes library and another one for the iPhoto library (they are pretty heavy), do you think this makes my Mac faster or not? And, if possible, can you shortly explain why?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does partitioning a hard drive give a performance gain?](http://superuser.com/questions/375354/does-partitioning-a-hard-drive-give-a-performance-gain), http://superuser.com/questions/199203/do-operating-systems-run-faster-on-smaller-hard-disk-partitions, http://superuser.com/questions/493314/is-there-a-performance-advantage-in-having-my-hdd-split-into-partitions,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only at the moment you start iTunes and iPhoto at the same time. And only if they're on separate disks. iTunes does not read a lot of data from the library when it's running, music does not use that much bandwidth. iPhoto reads the library on start but more memory would be a better choice.